# Is Visual Studio Tools for Applications part of Office 2007?

Tags: excel, ms-office, vsta

The VSTO bit I understand. Visual Studio has the project templates to get you started with creating nice .NET based add-ins.

But where is VSTA?  I installed the SDK but it seems to be gears towards adding extensibility to your own applications.

I had thought that VSTA was like the new VBA for Office 2007.  Infopath 2007 seems to be VSTA enabled but I cannot seem to find where Excel 2007 is also VSTA enabled.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, VSTA is not a 'new VBA' nor built into Office 2007, but a separate 'Super-VBA with .NET' that must be licensed from Summit, and distributed as part of an external application.  I think it's just targeted at ISVs wishing to extend Office, but the blurb about it also contains this gem:

> Perhaps the feature most applauded by enterprise BDMs and SI’s is that VSTA customizations are seamlessly opened by any version of Visual Studio enabling professional developers to continue to enhance applications originally created by end user developers – a feature requested by many enterprises because applications often grow in sophistication over time.

I've not bothered googling BDMs and SI means le Système International d'Unités to me, but I took this mean that you can take the horrible mess of excel VBA that your traders used to turn worthless morgages into goldmine CDOs (and then bailouts), and your 'real developers' can open it in Visual Studio and sort the mess out (or just quit...).

also VBA and VSTA can exist together:
http://blogs.msdn.com/vsta/archive/2006/07/31/684514.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, VSTA is a new technology that provides a "standard" short-cut route to extensibility for application vendors. So it may appear in Office apps in the future or it may not, but it's not there now.

If it becomes supported by Excel, Word and the like, then the UI (Visual Studio Shell?) should be distributed as part of the package.

But I may be miles off-base...

Answer (score 0):

> VSTO 2005 is available to install by itself as a complete development environment

Read more here...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54ds2za4(v=vs.80).aspx